# SQL - For loop not iterating all rows

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I created a stored procedure in Redshift that loops through the result set of a select query and performs some operation. The select query returns 150 rows. But the for loops is not iterating through all the rows. It randomly stops in the middle. Can someone help?

```sql
create or replace procedure count_duplicates_in_xyz_tables() as $$
declare 
    table_row record;
    cnt bigint;
    idx int;
begin
idx := 0;
for table_row in select * from pg_tables t where schemaname = 'public' and trim(tablename) like '%_xyz' loop
    cnt := 0;
    idx := idx + 1;
    execute 'select count(*) from ' || table_row.tablename || ' where accountid in (123, 456, 789)' into cnt;
    raise info '[%] Rows count from %: %', idx, table_row.tablename, cnt;
end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

call count_duplicates_in_xyz_tables();

drop procedure count_duplicates_in_xyz_tables();
```

Comment: Are there any error messages?  Does it always stop at the same place?  And are you sure that every table named in `pg_tables` actually exists and is accessible by you/your procedure?

Comment: @RBarryYoung No, it doesn't stop at the same place everytime. It's completely random. Sometimes 23, 74, 121.. I didn't find any patterns. And yes, all tables in `pg_tables` exists  and are accessible. No error messages.